# Verifying that the identity functor is indeed a functor

Tags: category-theory, solution-verification

> The identity functor $1_{\mathscr C}:\mathscr C \to \mathscr C$ has $1_{\mathscr C}(a)=a$, $1_{\mathscr C}(f)=f$. Verify that it is indeed a functor, specifically that it is a function that assigns:
>
> 1. To each $\mathscr C$-object $a$, a $\mathscr C$-object $1_{\mathscr C}(a)$
> 2. To each $\mathscr C$-arrow $f:a\to b$ a $\mathscr C$-arrow $1_{\mathscr C}(f):1_{\mathscr C}(a)\to 1_{\mathscr C}(b)$ such that
>
>    - $1_{\mathscr C}(1_a)=1_{1_{\mathscr C}(a)}$ for all $\mathscr C$-objects $a$
>    - $1_{\mathscr C}(g\circ f)=1_{\mathscr C}(g)\circ 1_{\mathscr C}(f)$, whenever $g\circ f$ is defined

2i is where I do not understand. LHS is supposedly an arrow (because it is a functor applied to an arrow), while RHS is supposed to be an object (because it is an arrow applied to a functor applied to $a$) - so how can an arrow be identical to an object?

From the LHS we have $1_{\mathscr C}(1_a)\to 1_a$ by def. that $1_{\mathscr C}(f)=f$.

From the RHS, we have $1_{1_{\mathscr C}(a)}\to 1_a$ by def. that $1_{\mathscr C}(a)=a$. This looks identical to what I have for LHS above...but I don't actually know what this is - is this supposed to be an arrow now? How did we go from dealing with an object to an arrow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid confusion it might be better to use another notation for identity arrows here.

Doing so 2i states that:$$1_{\mathscr C}(\mathsf{id}_a)=\mathsf{id}_{1_{\mathscr C}(a)}$$

Note that *both* LHS and RHS are (identity) arrows.

Comment: Thank you, that was much clearer when being put that way